# Why does the tsc command not show compiling errors when used to compile a specific file?

Tags: typescript

I have a file called app.ts, it looks like this.

```
    interface  Foo {
    bar:String;
}

const fn = (foo? :Foo) => foo.bar;
```

Due to having `strict:true` in my tsconfig.json file I get a nice error when I run `tsc` from the root folder. The error looks like this.

```
app.ts:5:27 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

5 const fn = (foo? :Foo) => foo.bar;
```

This is exactly what I'd expect. However when I run `tsc app.ts` I get no error at all and the app.js file is produced! Not what I'd expect. Why is this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because `tsc` can either do an entire project (and account for `tsconfig.json`) or a single file, but not both.

When `tsc` is invoked with a single file, it doesn't look at `tsconfig.json` (see [this documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)).

> When input files are specified on the command line, **tsconfig.json files are ignored.**

(emphasis mine)

---

The reasoning behind that is a mystery to me though.

Comment: The other question is why tsc writes .js files for .ts files with errors. It does this whether you run it with a single file or an entire project. IMHO the compiler should not be generating invalid code.