# TSC doesn't output errors from "strict" in my terminal, but the GitHub Action fails

Tags: typescript, tsc

I'm currently working on a side project where I'm building a webapp with NodeJS written in TypeScript. I'm on Windows 11 and I'm using `tsc` to build the project. In my `compilerOptions` I have set `"strict": true`. Thus, I'd expect some errors in this line (since `socket` and `request` are implicitly of type `any`):

```
server.on("connection", (socket, request) => {
```

The problem, however, is that it doesn't show those errors when I run `tsc.cmd -p tsconfig.server.json`. It does show the errors in the GitHub Action I set up, though: `Error: src/server/main/app.ts(19,26): error TS7006: Parameter 'socket' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

I don't think it's a duplicate from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645072/why-does-the-tsc-command-not-show-compiling-errors-when-used-to-compile-a-specif) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74589376/strict-mode-typescript-checks-fails-from-tsconfig-json) because I use `-p tsconfig.server.json` instead of calling `tsc` on a file.
I do think it's very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75269388/tsc-build-errors-during-github-action-but-compiles-fine-locally) which hasn't received a single answer in 4 months and I didn't know how to "re-ask" that question without posting a new one, which is why I am writing this.

The relevant parts of `tsconfig.server.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // ...
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "include": ["src/server/**/*"]
}
```

The relevant parts of `src/server/main/app.ts`:

```
server.on("connection", (socket, request) => {
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that not downloading the correct node modules gives a lot of TS errors... Adding `- uses: npm install` fixed everything for me.

Comment: What is -uses? Where did you put that?

Comment: @ShadowGames it's in the GitHub workflow file. I forgot to install all the packages that I'm using before building the project in the workflow.